# jQuery persist all event listeners on element for future setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Using jQuery I need to:

1. persists list of all event handlers that are added to element,
2. remove them all for few seconds and
3. return things to initial state (reassign the same event handlers)

I found that get list of current listeners with (some jQuery inner mechanisms):

```
var eventsSubmitBtn = $._data(submitButton[0], "events");
```

Then I can remove all event listeners with

```
 submitButton.off();
```

But last stem seems not to be working

```
 setTimeout(function () {
      $._data(submitButton[0], "events", eventsSubmitBtn);
    }, 5000);
```

`eventsSubmitBtn` is an empty array.

**Is this the way this should be done with initial setting and I'm need something like deep cloning for those objects or this can't be done with `$._data`?**

**N.B.  I have possibility to add my cistom code after all other system js code, thus I can't place the code assigning to `$.fn.on` before anything. Code that I write will run the last on startup and other event listeners are attached before my scripts will run.**

Comment: Try this one 
var eventsSubmitBtn = Object.assign({},$._data(submitButton[0], "events"))

Comment: `$._data` does not cover all event handlers. E.g. `submitButton.click = function () { } ` will not be present in that list.

Comment: @trincot but if my all event handlers were added by jQuery means (`.on()`) then it should work as I understand, right?

Comment: Yes, if you take a shallow copy (see first comment), but then still you are going against jQuery instructions. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

As you get a reference to the object returned by `$._data()`, any change to that object will not go unnoticed, i.e. after you invoke `.off()`, that object will have changed to reflect that there are no handlers attached any more.

You could solve this by taking a shallow copy of the object, (e.g. with `Object.assign`).

But this is not really a recommended way to proceed. According to a [jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/), *"`jQuery._data(element, "events")` ... is an internal data structure that is undocumented and should not be modified."*. As you are modifying it when restoring the handlers, this cannot be regarded best practice. But even only reading it should only be used for debugging, not production code.

It would be more prudent to put a condition in your event handling code:

```
var ignoreEventsFor = $(); // empty list

$("#button").on('click', function () {
    if (ignoreEventsFor.is(this)) return;
    // ...
});
```

Then, at the time it is needed, set `ignoreEventsFor` to the element(s) you want to ignore events for. And when you want to revert back to normal, set it to `$()` again.

Now adding this to all your event handlers may become a burden. If you stick to using `on()` for attaching event handlers, then you could instead extend `$.fn.on` so it will add this logic to the handlers you pass to it.

The following demo has a button which will respond to a click by changing the background color. With a checkbox you can disable this from happening:

```js
/* Place this part immediately after jQuery is loaded, but before any 
   other library is included 
*/
var ignoreEventsFor = $(), // empty list
    originalOn = $.fn.on;
$.fn.on = function (...args) {
    var f = args[args.length-1];
    if (typeof f === 'function') {
        args[args.length-1] = function (...args2) {
            if (ignoreEventsFor.is(this)) return;
            f.call(this, ...args2);
        };
    }
    originalOn.call(this, ...args);
}
/* This next part belongs to the demo, and can be placed anywhere */
$(function () {
    $("#colorButton").on('click', function () {
        // Just some handler that changes the background
        var random = ('00' + (Math.random() * 16*16*16).toString(16)).substr(-3);
        $('body').css({ backgroundColor: "#" + random });
    });

    $("#toggler").on('change', function () {
        // Toggle the further handling of events for the color button:
        ignoreEventsFor = $(this).is(':checked') ? $("#colorButton") : $();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="colorButton">Change color</button><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggler">Disable events
```

Notice: the above code uses ES6 spread/rest syntax: if you need support for IE then that would have to be written using the `arguments` variable, `apply`, ...etc.

Comment: Thank for great answer. I have power over small code in `overrides.js` for one system and I can follow this approach if I managed all event listeners, but this is not my case. Thus I need to get all event listeners - set by me or be anything else.

Comment: In comments you said that they were all set using `.on()`, so if you place the code assigning to `$.fn.on` before any other library (except jQuery) is included, it should work. If however other methods are used for attaching event handlers, then I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: I have possibility to add `overrides.js` after all other system js code , thus I can't place the code assigning to `$.fn.on` before anything. You understood my comment right. I also thought about having a flag I can turn on to achieve this, but these are not my circumstances.

Comment: Are the other scripts added in the `head` element or near the end of the `body` element?

Comment: **Yes** e.g. for Login page in my system I have 2 scripts added in head. then in body in different places 6 inline scripts and my "overrides" are appended as the last part of the body.

Comment: Well, the ones in the `head` cannot assign event handlers immediately, as the DOM is not built yet. For the other inline scripts it is a question mark, since they would only have synchronous access to the part of the DOM that is built before their own `script` element. So there still is a chance that if you do this `$.fn.on` assignment, you'll be ahead of most, and maybe all calls on `on()`.